# Visual Studio font colors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I know this is a stupid question but I use `Visual Studio Ultimate` and for `C#` language, it has all different colors and fonts for classes and functions and better intellisense, and for `C++` it does not. I mainly code in `C++` and I would like to know if there is an option to have this for `C++` too, becausee it feels much more comfortable and more easy to read

Comment: Do you want to change the colors and fonts similar to C# only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Fonts` and `Colors` are **global** for `Visual Studio Editor` and not specific to Languages/Context..

You could change it  @ `Tools -> Options -> Enviornment -> Fonts and Colors`

But `Formatting` are specific to languages

You could update it @ `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Import and
Export Settings: 
Click Next and ONLY export the Fonts and Colors
NOTHING ELSE:
Click Next then give the settings a cool name and click Finish :).